# Setting custom (lookup) field value for enterprise resource in Project Server 2013

Tags: development, csom, project-server

I am using CSOM in order to import Enterprise Resources in Project Server 2013 from an external file. Resources, in my case, have some custom fields. The code is the following:

```
    private static void InitializeContext()
    {
        Context = new ProjectContext(PwaPath);
        Context.Credentials = Credentials;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeContext();

        // Load resources and custom fields
        Context.Load(Context.EnterpriseResources);
        Context.Load(Context.CustomFields);
        Context.Load(Context.LookupTables);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();

        var newResourceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var newResourceInfo = new EnterpriseResourceCreationInformation
        {
            Id = newResourceId,
            IsBudget = false,
            IsGeneric = false,
            IsInactive = false,
            Name = "AName",
            ResourceType = EnterpriseResourceType.Work
        };
        Context.EnterpriseResources.Add(newResourceInfo);
        Context.EnterpriseResources.Update();
        Context.Load(Context.EnterpriseResources);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();
        EnterpriseResource newResource = Context.EnterpriseResources.GetByGuid(newResourceId);
        LookupTable lTable = Context.LookupTables.First(lut => lut.Name == "SomeText");
        Context.Load(lTable.Entries);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();
        LookupEntry entry = lTable.Entries.First(c => c.FullValue.EndsWith("SomeText"));
        CustomField cField = Context.CustomFields.First(c => c.Name == "aValue");
        newResource[cField.InternalName] = entry.FullValue;
        Context.EnterpriseResources.Update();
    }
```

The last 2 lines of code should update the value (read from a lookup table) of the field, but they don't. Anybody has any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

P.s: This question is also asked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083185/setting-custom-lookup-field-value-for-enterprise-resource-in-project-server-20). In case it should be deleted just let me know and I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss `Context.ExecuteQuery();` after `Context.EnterpriseResources.Update();`

The below simple example show how to update a resource custom field that uses a value that is picked up from a Lookup table by using CSOM that I think can help you.

```
var cfInternalName = "Custom_aaf4156c7804e511943500155d569905";
            foreach (EnterpriseResource res in resources)
            {
                string[] Newval = new string[] { "Entry_333982d27604e511943500155d569905" };     //Lookup table row value UID without "-"   and small letters                                             
                res[cfInternalName] = Newval;                               
            }
            projContext.EnterpriseResources.Update();
            projContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

For more details check [how to update a resource custom field that uses a value that is picked up from a Lookup table by using CSOM?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4d3ee63-965b-4489-8b34-6ad53b128553/csom-update-custom-field-based-on-lookup-table?forum=project2010custprog)

Comment: thanks for the reply. It helped a lot. What I was doing wrong was assigning the wrong value to the field and, as you mentioned, omitting the `Context.ExecuteQuery();` command. It should've been `newResource[cdcField.InternalName] = new string[] { cdcEntry.InternalName };` and not `newResource[cdcField.InternalName] = cdcEntry.FullValue;`

Comment: Good Job my bro ,